# Fixing cv::convertPointsFromHomogeneous Error

Tags: c++, opencv

I used `convertPointsFromHomogeneous` function to convert homogeneous coordinates(4D) to 3D.

But I get some error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (npoints >= 0) in cv::convertPointsFromHomogeneous, file fundam.cpp, line 879

Please tell me what was wrong.

The codes are as follows.

```
cv::Mat Thomogeneous(4,1,cv::DataType<double>::type); // translation vector
Thomogeneous.at<double>(0,0) = -70;
Thomogeneous.at<double>(1,0) = -95;
Thomogeneous.at<double>(2,0) = -120;
Thomogeneous.at<double>(3,0) = 1;

cv::Mat T(3,1,cv::DataType<double>::type); // translation vector
cv::convertPointsFromHomogeneous(Thomogeneous, T);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The input `Mat` to `convertPointsFromHomogeneous` should be a `N` channel `Mat` (in your case `N=4`), with type `CV_32F` or `CV_32S`.

You instead are passing a single channel `Mat` with type `CV_64F`.

You can correct your code like:

```
cv::Mat1f Thomogeneous(4, 1); 
Thomogeneous(0) = -70;
Thomogeneous(1) = -95;
Thomogeneous(2) = -120;
Thomogeneous(3) = 1;

// Reshape to 4 channel matrix
Mat Th = Thomogeneous.reshape(4);

cv::Mat T;
cv::convertPointsFromHomogeneous(Th, T);
```

Also note that you can use `Mat_<Tp>` (such as `Mat1f`, aka `Mat_<float>`), to make the code less verbose.